# When I take a picture my bluView turns transparent?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, uivisualeffectview

I have this rectangle that has a blur effect and when I take a picture the blur turns transparent. I have my `previewView` inside of my `ViewController`.  Why does that happen?

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        
        if let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() {
        if let cameraImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {
            
            
            // Create the image context to draw in
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(previewView.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)

            // Get that context
            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

            // Draw the image view in the context
            previewView.layer.render(in: context!)
            
            // Then grab the "screenshot" of the context
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            
            //combine new image and camera view
            let newImage2 = composite(image: cameraImage, overlay: image!, scaleOverlay: true)
            
            //show captured image
            captureImageView2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
            captureImageView2.image = newImage2
            self.view.addSubview(captureImageView2)


            //end the context
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        }
    }
}



//combine imageview with uiview
func composite(image:UIImage, overlay:(UIImage), scaleOverlay: Bool = false)->UIImage?{
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)
        var rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)
        image.draw(in: rect)
        if scaleOverlay == false {
            rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: overlay.size.width, height: overlay.size.height)
        }
        overlay.draw(in: rect)
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
}

//This code is in my PreviewView `UIView`
private func createLayer(in rect: CGRect) {
let darkBlur = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: darkBlur)

blurView.frame = rect
blurLayer.append(blurView)

insertSubview(blurView, at: 1)

}
```

Comment: Did you set alpha value for blurView ? Read doc: Setting the Correct Alpha Value
When using the UIVisualEffectView class, avoid alpha values that are less than 1. Creating views that are partially transparent causes the system to combine the view and all the associated subviews during an offscreen render pass. UIVisualEffectView objects need to be combined as part of the content they are layered on top of in order to look correct. Setting the alpha to less than 1 on the visual effect view or any of its superviews causes many effects to look incorrect or not show up at all.

Comment: Just tried it the blur is still transparent for some reason.

Comment: The only thing that works is if I set the `blurView` backgroundColor to white or black its not transparent anymore but doesn't show the blur.

Answer (score 0):

Ofc you get transparent, you draw in current context and clear layer ...

- create container
- create view for image ImageVC
- create view for blur  BlurVC
- setup blur in BlurVC
- add BlurVC to container
- add ImageVC to container
- draw image to context in ImageVC

add result container to preview